# Redis SocketFailure

Tags: c#, redis

I am new to Redis. I have implemented a class which has method for `GET, SET, DELETE and ISKEYPRESENT`. Following is the code of my class:

```
static ConnectionMultiplexer redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("connectionstring");
static readonly IDatabaseAsync dbConnection = redisConnection.GetDatabase();

        public static async Task SetRecordAsync<T>(string recordId, T data, TimeSpan? timeSpan = null)//default 30 mins
        {
            var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);

            if (timeSpan.HasValue)
            {
                await dbConnection.StringSetAsync(recordId, jsonData, timeSpan);
            }
            else
            {
                timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                await dbConnection.StringSetAsync(recordId, jsonData, timeSpan);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<T> GetValueAsync<T>(string recordId)
        {
            var data = await dbConnection.StringGetAsync(recordId);
            var jsonData = data.ToString();

            if (jsonData is null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonData);
        }

        public static async Task DeleteValueAsync(string recordId)
        {
            await dbConnection.KeyDeleteAsync(recordId);
        }

        public static async Task<bool> IsKeyNull(string recordId)
        {
            var value = await dbConnection.StringGetAsync(recordId);
            var isNull = value.IsNullOrEmpty ? true : false;
            return isNull;
        }
```

But I keep getting this error which I couldn't understand what it is trying to saying:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=No connection is active/available to service this operation: GET Order; A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: ASR-PC, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=8190,Min=4,Max=8191), v: 2.1x.58.3xyz
  Source=StackExchange.Redis
  StackTrace:
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ThrowFailed[T](TaskCompletionSource`1 source, Exception unthrownException) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2777
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at RedisCache.DistributedCacheExtensions.<IsKeyNull>d__4.MoveNext() in RedisCache\DistributedCacheExtensions.cs:line 67
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at BusinessLogic.Services.Order.OrderService.GetOnlineOrderCount(Int32 storeId) in OrderService.cs:line 1846
   at GetOnlineOrderCount(Int32 storeId) in Api\Controllers\Order\OrderController.cs:line 443
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Inner Exception 1:
RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on windows.net:6380/Subscription, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 10s ago, last-write: 10s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 10s ago, v: 2.x.58.3xyz

Inner Exception 2:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.

Inner Exception 3:
SocketException: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
```

My connection string for redis looks like this:

> windows.net:6380,password=xyz=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,connectTimeout=10000,connectRetry=8,syncTimeout=3000

Redis connection logs

```
redis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,syncTimeout=100000000,connectTimeout=100000000,password=*****,ssl=True,connectRetry=8

Connecting redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive...
BeginConnect: redis.cache.windows.net:6380
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from redis.cache.windows.net:6380 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 1.03:46:40 to respond...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=8190,Min=4,Max=8191)
Configuring TLS
connection failed: redis.cache.windows.net:6380 (Subscription, SocketFailure): SocketFailure on redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Subscription, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 30s ago, last-write: 30s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 30s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
connection failed: redis.cache.windows.net:6380 (Interactive, SocketFailure): SocketFailure on redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 30s ago, last-write: 30s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 30s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Finished awaiting tasks, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
redis.cache.windows.net:6380 faulted: SocketFailure on redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 30s ago, last-write: 30s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 30s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
Waiting for tiebreakers...
All tasks are already complete
redis.cache.windows.net:6380 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> SocketFailure on redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 30s ago, last-write: 30s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 30s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
No masters detected
redis.cache.windows.net:6380: Standalone v3.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Connecting; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
redis.cache.windows.net:6380: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
resetting failing connections to retry...
retrying; attempts left: 7...
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from redis.cache.windows.net:6380 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 1.03:46:40 to respond...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
Finished awaiting tasks, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
redis.cache.windows.net:6380 faulted: UnableToConnect on redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 30s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
Waiting for tiebreakers...
All tasks are already complete
redis-red
```

Comment: That *probably* means it was unable to connect - try removing the `abortConnect=False` and see if it gives you a more helpful error during `Connect`/`ConnectAsync`; also - try passing in a text-writer as the `log` parameter of `Connect`/`ConnectAsync` which can show you a lot more of what it is doing

Comment: btw: for `IsKeyNull` : note that redis doesn't have a concept of `null`, so what you are really testing here is "does it exist?" - and for that: `KeyExists(...)` is more efficient

Comment: I am just getting the value of the key. If the value doesnt exist for key then I am checking is it null or not.

Comment: yes, I can read the code; but: the only way you'll get `null` is if it doesn't exist; and you can do that via `KeyExists` *much more efficiently* than by fetching the value - it involves simpler operations and lower bandwidth requirements (especially for large values)

Answer (score 1):

### It's Probably an issue with TLS

Given your connection string `windows.net:6380,password=xyz=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,connectTimeout=10000,connectRetry=8,syncTimeout=3000` I'm going to take a stab in the dark and say your most likely issue is an issue with TLS. Most likely, your redis-server does not have TLS enabled. Interestingly, by setting `abortConnect` to false explicitly, the connection itself does not fail loudly up front.

### Try disabling TLS

The shortest path to getting your code working is probably to delete the `ssl=True` bit from the connection string. That will prevent the multiplexer from trying to do the tls negotiations with redis.

### If you really need TLS

If you need TLS, you'll need to make sure you:

1. Configure your server correctly (TLS enabled is not the default nor is it in the default build of Redis)
2. Configure the Multiplexer correctly

#### Configuring the Server

There's two paths to enabling tls in redis. First you could use a third-party redis provider, tls is a pretty standard feature for Redis Providers. Or, you can build Redis from source with the tls flags set and then load tls with your certs / ca files. Theres' a great writeup for this on [redis.io](https://redis.io/docs/manual/security/encryption/)

#### Configuring the client

With TLS enabled on your Redis Server you'll need to verify that your certificates and CA are both acceptable to the client, there's a couple routes to this. You can load the CA/cert on your machine's cert store. Or you can load them directly into the client, Here's an article about how to [configure TLS in the multiplexer](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_csharp/), The example shows how to connect to a Redis Cloud instance with TLS, but the steps apply to whatever certs/ca you are using

Comment: But when i am running simple console application like : ```Task task = DistributedCacheExtensions.SetRecordAsync<string>("Anir", "Rawa");
                task.Wait();
                var lp = DistributedCacheExtensions.GetValueAsync<string>("Anir").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                Console.WriteLine(lp);``` Then it is running fine with same connection string

Comment: How are you actually running your redis server?

Comment: Actually I don't know about how is my team running the server. They simply gave me the connection string and asked me to implement redis. I have tried set and get method on simple data types like string and int through console application. But when I am trying to implement with ASP.NET then I am seeing this issue.